# How to hide the next button when no pages to dispaly

Tags: php

Can someone help me please? I am sure it is easy for you guys. I am battling to find a solution on how to hide the next link when there are no pages to display my code is as follows:

```php
if (!isset($_GET['page']) or !is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = 0;
} else {
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
}
$pages_query=mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT * FROM hardware");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hardware LIMIT $page, 3");
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page+3).'">Next</a><p>';
$prev = $page - 3;

//only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
if ($prev >= 0) {
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$prev.'">Previous</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mysql_num_rows($result)` to get the number of records in hardware:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hardware LIMIT $page, 3");
$record_count =  mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($record_count > 1)
    echo 'Next';
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lazarus it worked like a charm, i really apreciate it. And thanks for everyone else who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

in your if statement check if the $page is greater than 0 then according to the outcome of the value of $page write your code. you  can use another if statement in the first if statement and make it detect the situation and decide what to do. The other thing is if the user clicked next then the user is on the second page so your previous should appear if $prev is higher than 1 it should make it

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of:

```
$itemsPerPage = 3;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hardware";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$pageCount = $count/$itemsPerPage;
if($pageCount > $page) { //Are there more pages worth of items stored, than we're currently looking at?
echo 'next';
}
```

You want to be using OFFSET in your SQL syntax, as well as LIMIT.

LIMIT limits the number of rows returned.
OFFSET tells it to start a number of rows into the result set.

You need to limit to the number of items you want on a page. and offset by that number*page.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: LIMIT with two parameters does offset and length at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much MWilson for the quick answer, your suggested answer works almost as i wanted, when i echo $count it shows 13 but, i run the code it shows me only 3x3 rows only, like 4 rows missing.